# What are the output files of the VxWorks Workbench kernel configuration GUI

Tags: configuration, kernel, vxworks, toolchain

I'm trying to generate a VxWorks 6.9.4.8 kernel configuration that is identical to another kernel workbench project. The Workbench 3.3.6 only allows GUI configuration.

Is there an underlying kernel configuration file, produced by the GUI, which can be replaced?

After updating the kernel configuration using the Workbench GUI, I see the following files have changed:

- linkSyms.c,
- prjComps.h,
- prjConfig.c, and
- prjParams.h

I guess my question is, which one, if any uniquely identifies the kernel as built?

Comment: As author of the question's post, you needn't to use comments for provide additional information: [edit] the question post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prjComps.h will contain all the component's names, as you have chosen in your kernel configuration GUI.

First step  to create new Kernel configuration based on some other Kernel configuration is to use GUI configurator and add the missing component in prjComps.h, Better use some diff tool like 'beyond compare', and keep reducing the differences by adding/removing the components. Remember not to edit this file directly, but via GUI configurator only. As the tool calculates the dependent component and adds/removes them.
Second step is to create the new prjParams.h as above.

The Workbench actually allows to use command line to edit Kernel configuration via vxprj tool in vxworks 6.9(this tool has been replaced by "wrtool" in vxworks 7), you can right click on the Image project and chose 'Open Wind River vxWorks 6.9 Developement Shell'.

If you want to add a component for e.g. telnet client (INCLUDE_TELNET_CLIENT)
, you can use the following command

```
 vxprj component add INCLUDE_TELNET_CLIENT
```

To remove a component

```
 vxprj component remove INCLUDE_TELNET_CLIENT
```

For more of vxprj tool, you can look up the documentation in the workbench itself.

Answer (score 1):

The project configuration is held in a handful of files in the kernel project directory.

These are:

1. .project
2. .cproject
3. .wrproject
4. projectname.wpj

Files such as prjComps.h, prjParams.h prjConfig.c are all generated by the configuration tool, however these are not configuration files themselves. Instead, this is generated C code that contains, amongst other things, a list of selected components.

These files are also re-generated, I believe, when you rebuild the project.
As such, these are not really the authoritative source you are interested in.

For this, you need to look at the project files. In terms of a list of components, the most interesting is the .wpj file, which contains amongst other things a list of explicitly and implicitly included components.

The explicitly included components are those you manually selected in the Kernel Configuration GUI, the implicitly included are those that were then included to satisfy dependencies.

This distinction can sometimes make comparing kernel configurations tricky, then you may want to fall back on the generated files eg prjComps.h, however you should always remember that this is a representation of the configuration, not the source.

The .project etc configuration files are big and complex, but a decent diff tool, such as BeyondCompare can make comparisons of the project directories fairly easy

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clue, @endTunnel.  I looked at that file, and noticed that a few files get modified when I save my GUI selections.

1. prjComps.h - all the components #included in the kernel build
2. prjParams.h - the additional parameters set for the enabled components
3. prjConfig.c - the configuration and initialization calls for each module included.

'linkSyms.c' also gets modified. Not sure how that is used, yet.

I can now use diff to compare kernel configurations, and perhaps even duplicate a configuration (haven't tried that yet).